# How to avoid duplication between plain libraries and universal libraries?

Tags: c#, .net, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal

I have a solution consisting of 2 parts:

- A normal Windows Library (compiling against Any CPU Windows)
- A universal library (compiling against Windows 10 platform)

Those 2 projects share a set of configuration values, for example, since they communicate over sockets, the port number of the endpoint. So I end up doing this:

```
// In Proj1/service.cs
namespace Proj.Lib {
  public class Service {
    private string port = "6662";
  }
}

// In Proj2/service.cs
namespace Proj.UniversalApp {
  public class Service {
    private string port = "6662";
  }
}
```

The two projects basically compile against different platforms, thus I cannot reference one into the other in order to avoid the redundancy on `port`.

The ideal solution for me would be to create a common project holding the variables in common and reference it both in `Proj1` (`Proj.Lib`) and `Proj2` (`Proj.UniversalApp`).

How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a portable class library (PCL) and have it target the two platforms that your projects target. you will then be able to reference the common project/library.

[Cross-Platform Development with the Portable Class Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg597391(v=vs.110).aspx)

> The .NET Framework Portable Class Library project type in Visual
>   Studio helps you build cross-platform apps and libraries for Microsoft
>   platforms quickly and easily.
>
> Portable class libraries can help you reduce the time and costs of
>   developing and testing code. Use this project type to write and build
>   portable .NET Framework assemblies, and then reference those
>   assemblies from apps that target multiple platforms such as Windows
>   and Windows Phone.
>
> Even after you create a Portable Class Library project in Visual
>   Studio and start developing it, you can change the target platforms.
>   Visual Studio will compile your library with the new assemblies, which
>   helps you identify the changes you need to make in your code.